# Java server on OpenShift

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, jdbc, openshift

At the moment i have an android client app which connects to my java server through socket - serversocket. It sends and receive strings. The java server is connected to a mysql database (actually mariadb) using the jdbc driver.

I succeed to create a jbossas application and upload the code of the java server to openshift, but i didn't find any detailed tutorial on how do i connect to this new uploaded server from my socket client (This one ([RMI or socket connection to Java Program on OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658848/rmi-or-socket-connection-to-java-program-on-openshift)) gives some tips but i'm still stucked).

More on this, how do i know that my server runs just fine on openshift and how do i control de calls to the database after i connect it (found this: $ rhc app create MyApp jbossas-7
$ rhc cartridge add mysql-5.5 -a MyApp), using org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver and java.sql is still working ?

Any small guide or tip is highly appreciated. I'm new to these things so please don't be too heavy on comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can only make connections to your OpenShift server on http/https or ws/wss ports.  If you want to connect to your java application and pull data from it from an android device, I would suggest using a RESTful api or a servlet, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem: My app server originally was running as a ServerSocket listener, and any clients/devices connect to it directly via Socket binding.

To deploy it into OpenShift, my previous initial solution was to change its host:port configuration by following the suggestion as described in this link [[Socket connection to Java Program on OpenShift]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658848/rmi-or-socket-connection-to-java-program-on-openshift). It worked nice as far as my app server was successfully up and running. But it did not work well with the port forwarding approach in order to accept remote requests.

So for the final solution, I modified the app server by **wrapping** my original code with a RESTful webservice around it, and deploy it as a web service.